# Different Python versions

Tags: python, python-2.7, fedora

On my Fedora 10, I have compiled python 2.7.9 successfully and when I run `python --version`
 I get 
**Python 2.7.9**   (correct)
 but when I run 
`sudo python --version`
 I get 
**Python 2.5.2**
 which I had yum installed before but wasn't able to update (old Fedora).
Also when I run
`su -c 'python --version'`
 I get
"Python 2.7.9"

This causes applications that require new python to not work and libraries to install only to my old python.

ex:
"playonlinux"
output:

```
ImportError: No module named wxversion
sudo playonlinux
Looking for python2... 2.5.2 - skipped
```

Is there any way to fix this and/or copy all my python 2.5 libraries to my 2.7?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to consider updating Fedora itself. You are 11 versions out of date. Your version of Fedora reached end of life more than 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Run "which python" as a regular user and as superuser.

Then check the $PATH variable (echo $PATH) as a regular user and as a superuser.

It's possible the regular user is searching in different locations than the superuser.  If that's the case, you may need to either alter the superuser's PATH or overwrite the python executable run by the superuser with a link pointing to the current version.

Just be careful to make sure any changes you make can be undone.  Also look for any environment variables such as PYTHONPATH under the superuser, it would not do to have that pointing to the wrong version of your python library!

Also, it would be good to update your version of Fedora, as these pain points will only continue to accumulate.

I would advise against copying package binaries between versions, as they could have been compiled against incompatible C libraries.

Finally, you should look into the virtualenv command, it simplifies juggling different versions of libraries for different projects.